# Simple quiz with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple quiz system only using javascript and HTML with no external libraries. But I ran into some problems. The script is giving the wrong solution. Even when I select the right checkboxes it only outputs 1 correct answer. I don't know what exactly am I doing wrong, or if there's an alternative way for doing this.

```html
<div class="quizsection">
    <button onclick="startQuiz()" id="startQuiz">Start Quiz</button>
    <div id="questions"></div> 
</div>

<script>
    //Create Array with questions and solutions
    var allQuestions = [{
        question: "Before Mt. Everest was discovered, whaich mountain was considered to be the highest mountain in the world?",
        choices: ["Mt. Kilimanjaro", "Kanchenjunga", "Mount Everest"],
        correctAnswer: 1
      },

      {
        question: "Does England have a 4th of July?",
        choices: ["Yes", "No", "I don't know"],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      {
        question: "What is Rupert the bear's middle name?",
        choices: ["Bear", "He doesn't have one!", "The", "Rupert"],
        correctAnswer: 2
      },

      {
        question: " What can you never eat for breakfast? ",
        choices: ["Dinner", "Something sugary", "Lunch", "Supper"],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      {
        question: "If there are three apples and you took two away, how many do you have?",
        choices: ["One", "Two", "None"],
        correctAnswer: 1
      },

      {
        question: "Spell 'Silk' out loud, 3 times in a row. What do cows drink?",
        choices: ["Milk", "Water", "Juice", "Cows can't drink"],
        correctAnswer: 1
      },

      {
        question: "Which is heavier, 100 pounds of rocks or 100 pounds of gold? ",
        choices: ["100 pounds of rocks", "100 pounds of rocks", "They weigh the same"],
        correctAnswer: 2
      },

      {
        question: "Can you spell 80 in two letters?",
        choices: ["AI-TY", "It's not possible", "EIGH-TY", "A-T"],
        correctAnswer: 3
      },

      {
        question: "What question must always be answered ''Yes''?",
        choices: ["What does Y-E-S spell?", "Will everyone die someday?", "Does everyone have a biological mother?", "Are you a human?"],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      {
        question: "How many sides does a circle have?",
        choices: ["The back", "None. It's a circle", "Two", "Four"],
        correctAnswer: 2
      },

      {
        question: "What has a tail but no body?",
        choices: ["A human", "A coin", "A cloud"],
        correctAnswer: 1
      },

      {
        question: "What word in the English language is always spelled incorrectly?",
        choices: ["It's possible to spell anything right as long as you learn it", "Shakespeare", "Onomatopoeia", "Incorrectly"],
        correctAnswer: 3
      },

      {
        question: "When do you stop at green and go at red?",
        choices: ["Watermelon!", "Traffic light!", "Garden"],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      {
        question: "What rotates but still remains in the same place?",
        choices: ["Bottle (spin the bottle game)", "Clock", "Stairs"],
        correctAnswer: 2
      },

      {
        question: "How can you lift an elephant with one hand?",
        choices: ["Truck", "Use both hands!", "Use a lever", "There is no such thing"],
        correctAnswer: 3
      }
    ];

//Function to start the quiz
function startQuiz(){
    
    var i;
    var j;
    var k;
    for(i=0; i<allQuestions.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='<form id="question">Q'+(i+1)+': '+ allQuestions[i].question;
        
        for(j=0; j<allQuestions[i].choices.length; j++){
         document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ allQuestions[i].choices[j] +'" id="value4" type="checkbox" />' + allQuestions[i].choices[j] + '<br/>';
         }
     document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='</form><br/><br/>';
    }
    
    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<button onclick="solveQuiz()">Solve Quiz</button>';
    
}

function solveQuiz(){
     var x;
        var txt = ' ';
        var i = 0;
        var correct = 0; 
        for(i = 0; i < document.forms[i].length;i++) { 
         x = document.forms[i]; 
         if(x[i].checked) { 
             correctAnswer = allQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
                if(x[i].value == allQuestions[i].choices[correctAnswer]){
                 correct += 1;
                }
            }
         }
        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += 'Correct answers: ' + correct;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you know one thing javascript run in client side . so user can easily inspect the element using browser developer tool .  so user will know the answer easily from your array . so think about it

Comment: A good way to debug is to place `console.log()` statements at different breakpoints in your code. In your particular case, I would place them in the `solveQuiz` function to see where it fails.

Comment: @JYoThI yes I do, but there's no problem as this will not be for public use.

Comment: All of your checkboxes have the id of `value4` change to `value'+j+'` and Use radio , rather than checkbox. Give them all the same `name=""` for each question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function solveQuiz(){
  var x;
  var txt = ' ';
  var i = 0;
  var correct = 0; 
  for(i = 0; i < document.forms.length;i++) { 
    x = document.forms[i]; 
    for(j = 0; j<x.length; j++){
      if(x[j].checked) { 
        correctAnswer = allQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
        if(x[j].value == allQuestions[i].choices[correctAnswer]){
          correct += 1;
        }
      }
   }
 }
 document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += 'Correct answers: '+ correct;
}
```

you can replace your solveQuiz fn with above block; 
Its better to use radio instead of checkbox;

```
    document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ allQuestions[i].choices[j] +'" id="value4" type="radio" />' + allQuestions[i].choices[j] + '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `startQuiz` you generate more form with same id and also input inside has always the same id for all questions. Try to concatenate id of these elements with for counter index.

Comment: I have done that already, but still unable to find the error. For some reason it's the for loop only seems to be checking once with 'i=2'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16868145)

Comment: Thanks for hint, I will make when I will can do it

Comment: @ewwink Thanks for hint, I will make when I will can do it